# IRC Twitch somehow start ignoring messages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just trying to make a 'Twitch Plays' game. I used a tutorial for making Twitch Plays games. I need to re-run this code every five minutes as it ignores the messages. I'm making Threes game on Scratch. I checked for all the possible bugs and it works very well. This game is based on moving tiles that contain numbers on them. Any suggestions regarding the IRC twitch ignoring all messages will be highly appreciated.

The code is shown here below.

```py
import socket
import pyautogui
import time

SERVER = "irc.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667
PASS = "oauth:fz5kp09su0lz46vnos78sklvpjnu6l"
BOT = "TwitchBot"
CHANNEL = "olejika2016"
OWNER   = "olejika2016"
message = ""
irc = socket.socket()
irc.connect((SERVER,PORT))
irc.send((  "PASS "+PASS+"\n"+
            "NICK "+BOT+"\n"+
            "JOIN #"+CHANNEL+"\n").encode())



def twitch():
    def joinchat():
        loading = True
        while loading:
            readbuffer_join = irc.recv(1024)
            readbuffer_join = readbuffer_join.decode()
            for line in readbuffer_join.split("\n")[0:-1]:
                # print(line)
                loading = loadingComplete(line)
    def loadingComplete(line):
        if ("End of /NAMES list" in line):
            print("Bot has joined "+CHANNEL+"'s channel")
            sendMessage(irc, "Chat Room Joined")
            return False
        else:
            return True
    def sendMessage(irc, message):
        messageTemp = "PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :" + message
        irc.send((messageTemp+"\n").encode())
    def getUser(line):
        separate = line.split(":", 2)
        user = separate[1].split("!",1)[0]
        return user
    def getMessage(line):
        global message
        try:
            message = (line.split(":",2))[2]
        except:
            message = ""
        return message

    joinchat()

    while True:
        try:
            readbuffer = irc.recv(1024).decode()
        except:
            readbuffer = ""
        for line in readbuffer.split("\r\n"):
            if line == "":
                continue
            else:
                # print("2;"+line)
                user = getUser(line)
                message = getMessage(line)
                print(user+":"+message)
                def writeUser():
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    pyautogui.typewrite(user)
                    pyautogui.press('enter')
                if message.lower() == "w":
                    pyautogui.press('up')
                    writeUser()
                if message.lower() == "s":
                    pyautogui.press('down')
                    writeUser()
                if message.lower() == "a":
                    pyautogui.press('left')
                    writeUser()
                if message.lower() == "d":
                    pyautogui.press('right')
                    writeUser()
                else:
                    pass
                user = ''
                message = ''

twitch()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for line in readbuffer.split("\r\n"):
            if line == "":
                continue
            elif "PING" is line and Console(line):
                msgg = "PONG tml.twitch.tv\r\n".encode()
                irc.send(msgg)
                print(msgg)
                continue
            else:
                user = getUser(line)
                message = getMessage(line)
                print(user+":"+message)
```